# Powershell : enable virtual machine creation and the maximum number of virtual machines (252) on a devTestLab's subnet

Tags: azure, powershell, virtual-machine, azure-powershell, powershell-az-module

I'm working on a powershell script to enable virtual machine creation and the maximum number of virtual machines (252) on a devTestLab's subnet :
[image: Azure Subnets]

I tried to use the IpConfigurations function but it always returns "null" with my subnet unfortunately :

```
       $subnetCree = Get-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name $subnetName -VirtualNetwork $vnet
            write-host $subnetCree.IpConfigurations
            if ($subnetCree.IpConfigurations -ne $null) {
                  
            $subnetCree.IpConfigurations[0].PrivateIpAddressAllocationMethod = "Dynamic"
            $subnetCree.IpConfigurations[0].ApplicationGatewayBackendAddressPools = @()
            $subnetCree.IpConfigurations[0].ServiceEndpoints = @()
            $subnetCree.IpConfigurations[0].LoadBalancerBackendAddressPools = @()
            $subnetCree.IpConfigurations[0].LoadBalancerInboundNatRules = @()
            $subnetCree.IpConfigurations[0].MaximumVMs = 252
            }else{
                write-host "ip configuration null"
            }
```

Here is what it returns to me :
[image: resultConsole]

I also tried with this function :

```
$subnetCree.MaxVMsPerUser = 252
```

But I have this result:

`Property 'MaxVMsPerUser' could not be found in this object. Verify that it exists and can be set.`

Anyone have an idea please? Thanks very much.

Comment: What does `$subnetCree` output if you write that out to the console, without specifying a sub-object?

Comment: Have you set two machines to the same IP address?

Comment: @AnthonyNorwood I verified that $subnetCree was not empty when displayed. Here is the result  : 
Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Network.Models.PSSubnet 

And $subnetCree.AddressPrefix gave me the correct address 10.24.59.0/24

Comment: @jdweng No I didn't

Comment: I think you need to configure the GateWay.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.network/add-azvirtualnetworkgatewayipconfig?view=azps-9.4.0.  You need a route the the subnet and the route is missing or the subnet is private.

Comment: @Halcoaching but you're not using `$subnetCree.AddressPrefix` in your script.

Comment: I tried many things but nothing seems to be able to script this option in Az Powershell and there is not a lot of documentation about this. Any idea ? Thank you.